# Change Color of Textarea Text as it is Typed In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am reading several arrays of words from a .JSON file.  I have the script set up so that when the user presses ENTER, his/her input is validated against the first element of this array.  If it is correct, it proceeds onto the next element in the array.  Before the user presses ENTER, I want each correct character entered to turn green, and each incorrect character to turn red.  This is ideal, but if it can't be done, I can settle with turning the entire string of user-entered text red/green based on an incorrect/correct character.

Is this possible?  I've heard that you cannot do this easily with a textarea, but that you could do it with other HTML tags with the contenteditable attribute.  Is there a plugin or library available for what I'm trying to achieve?  I looked into the colorfy plugin, but that seems to require a regex expression.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: If you want green and red, you'd have to use a WYSIWYG editor so that the words can be wrapped in spans. For one colour, just change the CSS `color` property.

Comment: Maybe this one http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/

Comment: I already have most of the code setup.  I just needed some API to change the color of the textarea text. The highlighttextarea jquery looks promising.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the WYSIWYG editor... so I will continue to look into it.  In the meantime, the highlighttextarea jquery will suffice.